# How can I restore my sublime text after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, sublime-text

How can I restore my sublime text after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10?

After upgrading I noticed the sublime launcher was missing from my Unity bar.
Can I restore it without reinstalling sublime? Version 3 I think.

Answer (score 0):

What about launching Sublime from a terminal say like 'sublime-text-2 & ' and then right click on the icon in the Unity bar and select 'Keep in the launcher' (or something like that since I am not localized in english) ?
It may do the trick.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Open Search (should be the top icon in the Launcher), and type in `sublime`. You should then be able to click on the icon to open the program, and once it's open the icon should appear in the Launcher. Right-click on the Sublime icon and select `Lock to Launcher`, and you should be all set.